# Azure Monitor - Barchart Stacked100

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to create an Azure Monitor Workbook "step" to create a *stacked100* graph.

This is easily achieved in Azure App Insights, but the same query refuses to render as a 100% graph and just gives a standard column chart

**Using APP INSIGHTS LOGS pane**

```
requests
| where name == "****"
| where url  == "****"
| summarize good=countif(duration < 30000), exceptions=countif(duration >= 30000) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render columnchart kind=stacked100
```

[image: App Insights]

**Using Azure Monitor Workbook**

Query is EXCACTLY the same as above

Workbook step settings

[image]

[image: Azure Monitor Workbook]

**Question: Is Stacked 100% not supported in Workbooks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbooks itself does not have a stacked100 version of the chart (not all of the options supported by the render operation are supported in workbooks)

In workbooks you'd have to compute the %'s yourself to create a stacked 100 chart

Comment: Well that's a PITA ... but this is actually what I have done as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question: Is Stacked 100% not supported in Workbooks?**

Yes, it works in Azure Monitor Workbooks too:

Query :

```
requests
|where name == "P1Notification"
| summarize good=countif(duration < 30000), exceptions=countif(duration >= 30000) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render columnchart kind=stacked100
```

Azure Monitor WorkBook:

[image]

App Insights:

[image]

The only difference is upside down of the chart.

Chart settings are default :

[image]

Comment: Then it is a very strange situation that I do not see this ...

Comment: Can you please let me know your "content/version" from the Advanced Editor JSON

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Xzvbyy3.png @ChrisHammond Its KqlItem/1.0